# How to remove auditlog from ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I my Ubunut 18.04 server there is a command running `auditlog` which consume ~100% of my CPU.
If I kill process finding PID it works fine for a day or so and then it's run again and consume my CPU.

Once I installed [mail server](https://modoboa.org/en/) in in my machine and later I remove it, I guess this could be a reason of auditlog, but I could not trace it.

Please help me to remove this service.

```
root     11710 87.7  0.2 715092  4684 ?        Ssl  Apr14 1709:42 auditlog
ubuntu   12059  0.0  0.0  14428  1004 pts/0    S+   10:47   0:00 grep --color=auto auditlog
```

Output of command: `cat /proc/9499/cmdline` is **auditlog**

and `ls -lF /proc/9499/fd/` output:

```
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 1 -> 'pipe:[7363932]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 10 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 11 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 12 -> 'socket:[7417752]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 2 -> 'pipe:[7363933]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 3 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 4 -> 'pipe:[7363997]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 5 -> 'pipe:[7363997]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 6 -> 'pipe:[7363996]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 7 -> 'pipe:[7363996]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 8 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 20 11:29 9 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
```

and nothing found with the command `grep -s -i auditlog /etc/cron* /etc/cron*/*`

Comment: Do you have slapd (openldap server) installed? That's the only package i can find in ubuntu that has a program called `auditlog` (and even that's a shared lib called auditlog.so).    If you don't have slapd installed, that's more than a bit suspicious, so can you edit your question and add the output for `cat /proc/11710/cmdline)?  or `cat /proc/$(pgrep auditlog)/cmdline` if it has already been killed and restarted.   The output of `ls -lF /proc/11710/fd/` would also be interesting - it will show what files the process has open.

Comment: also `grep -s -i auditlog /etc/cron* /etc/cron*/*`

Comment: @cas question updated

Comment: does `find / -iname auditlog -ls` show anything?   also, `lsof -p $(pgrep auditlog)` will show what files/directories the process is using, which should help you track down what/where it is.

Comment: also, it doesn't seem to be being restarted by cron (although I forgot to get you to grep for it in /var/spool/cron/crontab), so maybe it's being restarted by systemd.   try `grep -s -ir auditlog  /var/spool/cron/crontab/ /etc/systemd/ /usr/lib/systemd/ /lib/systemd/`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same and I'm afraid to say it is a crypto mining virus.

Your server is likely compromised, so your safest course of action is a rebuild.

EDIT:

I was asked about how I determined this.

I ran a `netstat` command, something like `netstat -antup` which listed outbound connections; from this I spotted the "auditlog" process was sending outbound requests to a server `static.88-99-193-240.clients.your-server.de`

I googled that address and it lead to this page:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/54726926874/ which mirrored exactly my issue and the author had done some significant analysis on this crypto mining bot. Helpfully there's a lot of detail there that may be useful.

Seperately (I don't know where) the advice was to rebuild the server as it was likely it could be compromised again.

Comment: Did you figure out anything more about the malware? I just found this on one of my servers. I could just rebuild it but I'd rather do a root cause analysis and figure out how it got here in the first place.

Comment: I suspet it was an FTP server with a weak password.

Comment: That also seems to have been the issue in my case.